# Error While create REST request for create file

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, file

I set the headers like following:
Headers:

```
accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
Authorization Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

{

  "apiUrl":"https://xxx.sharepoint.com",
  "overwrite":"true",
  "folderName":"/Document",
  "fileName":"zxc.txt",
  "filecontent":"abcdedwv",
  "accessToken":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

But It returned status: 500 Internal server error ,Please tell what could be the reson for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if it works, then modify it to your liking after it succeeds:

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files/Add(url='file name', overwrite=true)
method: POST
body: contents of binary file
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-length:length of post body
```